# Every ACTION_CALL intent considered call to emergency number?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to write a dialer (Android) for my grandma (easing her into smart phones -- default dialer is too intimidating; I've tried)...

...and I'm seeing that every ACTION_CALL gets sent to the default dialer on my test device (Blu Advance 4.0 L3, running Marshmallow).  My emulator's dialer does not exhibit this behavior.

My min sdk is 23 and I do have permissions requested and granted as per the new permissions protocols.

I've checked the logs and it appears every number (5555 in this example) gives:

"NewOutgoingCallIntentBroadcaster: Cannot call potential emergency number 55555 with CALL Intent" from the logs.

I looked up the vanilla source code: they do a check with PhoneNumberUtils to see if the number is an emergency number.  I've confirmed with code, however that PhoneNumberUtils does not claim every number is emergency.

How can this be?  Did the manufacturer actually change the source code (from com.android.server.telecom) ... or did they intercept the intent at some point with a broadcast receiver?  If it's the latter, is there any way to determine what receiver, and bypass it?  I wonder why they would bother to do this?  Is my only realistic option to do an overlay using "draw over other apps" permission?  Or just get her a different model of phone (I've tried rooting this one, to no avail)?

By the way, I've downloaded a couple dialer apps from the play store on this device and they also always bring up the default dialer instead of dialing directly, so it doesn't seem like I'm doing something wrong.